# Attachments in JavaMail and Microsoft Exchange 2007 are not received correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to receive emails from Microsoft Exchange 2007 using JavaMail API. If the email does not contain any attachment, all email is correctly received. But if email contains an attachment, the body of the message is received correctly, but the attachments are sent as content type html, so for example if an attachment is called blabla.pdf, it is sent as blabla.pdf.html, and the more interesting part is that the file does not contain html code nor data of original file.

Anybody knows why this behaviour of Exchange to change the attachments?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with EMC SourceOne which substitutes the attachments with html links to safe space :S